# Postgres: Speeding up a simple JOIN+FILTER+ORDER BY query that operates on "blocky" data

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a pretty simple Postgres `SELECT` query that operates on two tables `A` and `B`, where `A` contains a foreign key to `B`'s primary key in the `b_id` field:

```
SELECT 
    A.*, B.*
FROM
    A
INNER JOIN
    B
ON
    B.id = A.b_id 
WHERE 
    -- various conditions on A
    A.x == 3
    -- ...
    AND B.source = 'example' --source is indexed
ORDER BY
   A.created_at DESC NULLS LAST
LIMIT
    20
```

The fields `x` (*integer*), `created_at` (*datetime*) and `b_id` (*UUID*) on `A` as well as `source` (*character varying*) on `B` have B-Tree indexes, `b_id` has a foreign key contraint on `B`s primary key `id`. The primary keys of `A` and `B` are random `UUID`s:

```
Table "A"
Column       |           Type           |   Modifiers   
-------------+--------------------------+---------------
id           | uuid                     | not null
x            | integer                  |
b_id         | uuid                     | not null
created_at   | timestamp with time zone | default now()

Indexes:
     "a_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
     "ix_a_created_at" btree (created_at)
     "ix_a_x" btree (x)
     "ix_a_created_at_desc" btree (created_at DESC NULLS LAST)

Foreign-key constraints:
     "a_b_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (b_id) REFERENCES b(id)

Table "B"

Column    |           Type           |       Modifiers        
----------+--------------------------+------------------------
id        | uuid                     | not null
source    | character varying        | not null

Indexes:
    "b_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "ix_b_source" btree (source)
```

Postgres produces and executes the following query plan:

```
Limit  (cost=0.72..4290.05 rows=20 width=122) (actual time=25801.196..25801.261 rows=20 loops=1)
   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.72..14553904.10 rows=67861 width=122) (actual time=25801.195..25801.252 rows=20 loops=1)
         ->  Index Scan using a_created_at_desc on a  (cost=0.43..6230611.59 rows=2200076 width=122) (actual time=0.038..21791.638 rows=2060427 loops=1)
               Filter: ((x == 3)))
               Rows Removed by Filter: 3799305
         ->  Index Scan using b_pkey on b  (cost=0.29..3.77 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=0 loops=2060427)
               Index Cond: (id = a.b_id)
               Filter: ((source)::text = 'example'::text)
               Rows Removed by Filter: 1
 Total runtime: 25801.311 ms
```

To me this seems fine as Postgres makes use of the available indexes for the filtering and sorting.

However, the problem is that my data is very "blocky": Table `A` gets populated by a batch process that first creates a single row in `B` and then hundreds of thousands of associated rows in `A`. As the `source` value varies between individual batches this means that sorting `A` by creation date would yield large blocks of rows with identical `b_id` values.

So the problem -as far as I understand it- is that when Postgres performs the nested loop to fetch the relevant rows from `A`, it will need to iterate through many millions of rows before hitting the ones that are actually relevant to the query, which makes the execution very slow (> 1 second on a table with several million rows). If I remove the `ORDER BY` clause, the query finishes within a few milliseconds, which seems to confirm this hypothesis.

Is there anything I can do to speed this up?

Comment: Please add 1) table definitions, including indexes. 2) explain analyze, 3) (maybe) relevant tuning constants for your installation, to your question.

Comment: `Rows Removed by Filter: 3799305` Your a table is walked in the created_at order, via the index. This avoids a final sort, which is fine. But the selection on x will cause it to still need visiting all the rows (until 20 limit is reached). A composite index on {created_at, x} and/or another on { x, created_at} could possibly work. (BTW: personally, I think that primary keys based on uuids are not a good idea) Plus: there *could* be a normalisation problem, given 4/4 key elements

Comment: Even when removing the `x` filter query the runtime is still very slow, so in my opinion the reason for the slowness is the JOIN in combination with ORDER BY. Why are UUID's not a good idea?

Comment: 1) I don't believe that. If the "rows removed by filter" could be avoided, the first index scan could complete within a few disk pages, before reaching LIMIT. 2) uuid's are bulkier (need 128 bits storage at least) than ints (32bits) or bigints (64bits) Your indexes will be larger as well -> fewer values per page -> more index pages, both for the PK and the FK's.

Comment: The FK join on a.bid = b.id will profit from a supporting index on a.b_id. Or maybe even (a.b_id, a.x) and/or (a.x, a.b_id) And: the UUIDs as a PK / FK should probably be avoided.